# Looking for suggestions on how to clean up some conditional statements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refactoring

Developing a validation function in React. I fairly new and don't want to develop any bad habits while I'm learning so I'm looking for suggestions on how to clean up a block of code i have here.

The function checks input fields and if they're blank, it attaches the appropriate message to an array. Once all input fields are checked, if that array is empty then proceed to submitting form. If that array contains error messages then the message is displayed to screen (not shown)

```
validation = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let errors = []
    const {firstName, lastName, emailAddress, password, confirmPassword} = {...this.state}

    if(firstName.length === 0) errors.push('Please provide a value for First Name');
    if(lastName.length === 0) errors.push('Please provide a value for Last Name');

    if(password.length === 0){
      errors.push('Please provide a value for Password');
    }else if(password !== confirmPassword){
      errors.push('Passwords do not match');
    };

    if(emailAddress.length === 0) {
      errors.push('Please provide a value for Email Address');
    }else if(!emailRegex.test(emailAddress)){
      errors.push('Invalid email address');
    };

    this.setState({errors: errors})

    if(errors.length === 0) this.logIn()
  }

  logIn = () => {
    console.log('good to go')
  };
```

Just looking for ways to clean up my conditional statements, if possible! Thanks

Comment: I would say create custom component essentially a wrapper over input element for each fields and let each input element handle its own error rather than a common function for all.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. The saved error state goes in a conditional in my JSX, just above the form. So if there are empty values, a div will appear above the form. If you have an example to show me what you're talking about, I would appreciate that! Especially if you think it will cut down on my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like the below would suffice. You could simplify this greatly if you provided a generic error message such as `"Missing required value: <keyName>"`, as opposed to something specific for the field.

You'll also want to do a manual check to ensure `password` === `confirmPassword`, but I think you'll be able to work that piece out.

```
const emailRegex = <your regex>;
const hasLength = val => val && val.length !== 0;
```

**Validation Map**

```
const validators = {
  firstName: {
    validate: hasLength,
    message: 'Please provide a value for First Name'
  },
  lastName: {
    validate: hasLength,
    message: 'Please provide a value for Last Name'
  },
  password: {
    validate: hasLength,
    message: 'Please provide a value for Password'
  },
  emailAddress: [{
      validate: hasLength,
      message: 'Please provide a value for Email Address'
    },
    {
      validate: val => !emailRegex.test(val),
      message: 'Invalid email address'
    }
  ],
}
```

**Validator**

```
validation = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  let errors = []
  const state = {...this.state};

  Object
    .keys(state)
    .forEach(key => {
      let validator = validators[key];
      if (!validator) return;
      if (!Array.isArray(validator)) {
        validator = [validator]
      }
      validator.forEach(v => {
        if (!v.validate(state[key])) {
          errors.push(v.message)
        }
      })
    });

  this.setState({errors: errors})

  if (errors.length === 0) this.logIn()
}
```

Comment: I had to remove ! from emailRegex to get the email validation to work